# What is the equivalent of Matlab's cwtft() in Python? (continuous morlet wavelet transform)

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet

I'm trying to implement a Morlet wavelet transform as matlab does, but I couldn't find any equivalent function in python. I want to implement it like this:

```
s0  = 6/fs;  % smallest scale
ds = 0.001; % spacing between scales
NbSc = 3000; % number of scales
SCA = {s0,ds,NbSc, 'lin'}; % specify scales
cwtstruct = cwtft({data, 1/fs},'scales',SCA);
```

and get the same outputs as Matlab's `cwtstruct` does.

I've already seen PyWavelets but it doesn't let you specify the scales in that way nor gives the same outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is old, but in case you were wondering this should work or at least get you started.

I'm not sure what outputs in particular you're looking for, but Wxx is the scalogram (a 2D array in time-frequency space similar to a spectrogram).

If you're wanting the phase angle and modulus as shown in the Matlab help page, you might want to use the following wavelet : 'cmor30.0-60000.0'

Where the 30 is your desired bandwidth (think window width of a FFT) and 60000 is the central frequency of the wavelet.

```
import pywt
import numpy as np

fs=1e3
s0=6/fs
smax=3000
wave='morl'
scales=np.arange(s0,smax,1/fs)
Wxx,freq=pywt.cwt(data,scales,wave,sampling_period=1/fs)
freq=freq*fs
```